# Binding a CFC to cfselect box

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I am creating a form and for what ever reason, when using a `bindOnLoad` with a remote CFC, my default value doesn't seem to appear.

Here is the cfselect:

```
<cfselect name="edcs"
          id="edcs"
          multiple="false"
          bind="cfc:Components.requestSearch.getEDCs()" 
          bindonload="true"
          value="edc_nm"
          display="edc_nm">
    <option name="">Select an EDC</option>
</cfselect>
```

And here is the function:

```
<cffunction name="getEDCs" access="remote" returntype="query">
    <cfscript>
        var queryService = new Query();
        queryService.setDatasource("#APPLICATION.db2system#");
        queryService.setName("getEDCs");
        queryService.setUserName("#APPLICATION.db2logon#");
        queryService.setPassword("#APPLICATION.db2pass#");
        queryService.setSQL(
                "select distinct rtrim(edc_nm) as edc_nm 
                   from #APPLICATION.db2owner#.pms_account");

        var result = queryService.execute();
        var edcs = result.getResult();          

        return("#edcs#");       
</cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

So, when the page loads I see the `<option ...>` value displayed for a split second and then the list gets populated, and the `Select an ECD` disappears.  I need to have a choice for a null value, which is what the option is for.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Addition: According to the CF10 docs, I should be able to use the `<option>` html tag.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7afe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run across this issue with CFSELECTs and binding CFCs.  I have also been unable to add an `<option></option>` tag with a bound CFSELECT.  The best way would be to create the query and force the result to have the desired input on the top.  For example:

```
SELECT distinct 
    rtrim(edc_nm) as edc_nm_display,
    rtrim(edc_nm) as edc_nm_value
FROM #APPLICATION.db2owner#.pms_account
UNION
SELECT
'Select an EDC' as edc_nm_display,
'0' as edc_nm_value
FROM dual
ORDER BY 2
```

This will return your query with 'Select an EDC' on the top.
Also, as a check, I believe `<option name="">Select an EDC</option>` should be `<option value="">Select an EDC</option>`.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The query will need to return that value. Try adding it as a UNION statement.

Comment: something like this: `select distinct rtrim(edc_nm) as edc_nm from #APPLICATION.db2owner#.pms_account union select cast(null as char(10)) as edc_nm from #APPLICATION.db2owner#.pms_account`

Comment: Yes. I don't know your data so you might need to add a column to order by but thats the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Return is not a function ...

```
return("#edcs#");
```

Try changing your function to ...

```
var result = queryServices().execute().getResult();
return result;
```